# Cannot load Report using Report Viewer Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am using VS 2008 and SQL 2008,.I am trying to build a report using Report viewer using Parameters.I am completly new to this concept,so i was trying to develop using the basic steps as shown in various tutrials.

1> connect to dataset

2- Configure server

3 - table Adapter

4 - Add new report

5 - Drag a table in the Report screen and add the columns

6 *  Here i am adding parameters ( fromdate,todate).Please tell me what mistake i am doing

I got to Reports -> ReportParamaters -> Add new Parameter - > fromdate -> type : Datetime. (Same for Todate)

7 - > In the web page. Added 2 textboxes and a button

8 - > Dragged Reportviewer - > choose Datasoure and Report name

Now the code Behind.

On button click

```
Protected Sub btnView_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnView.Click
        Try
            setReportParameters()
            Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

 Private Sub setReportParameters()
        Dim Fromdate As New ReportParameter("Fromdate", tbFromDate.Text)
        Dim Todate As New ReportParameter("Todate", tbtodate.Text)

        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {Fromdate, Todate})

    End Sub
```

When i Run the Report I get this Following Error

"

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
    Error during processing of ‘FromDate’ report parameter.
```

All i can see is the textboxes and Button.When i click on it,nothing happens...

Please help

"

Answer (score 0):

I see two things to check:

1.) You set the parameter "fromdate" with the parameter "Fromdate", I believe this is case sensitive.

2.) Fromdate in the report is a datetime, you are passing a string (tbFromDate.Text)  Make sure this is a valid date.

```
 Dim Fromdate As New ReportParameter("Fromdate", cDate(tbFromDate.Text))
```

Comment: Well..I changed fromdate to FromDate...And also the Datetime.but it throws the same Error.:(

Answer (score 0):

A couple more things to check.

1. Verify that the parameter in the report is a DateTime data type.
2. You might need to format the date as well. I've used this in the past with success:

   `ReportParameter startAtParam = new ReportParameter("StartAt", startAt.ToString("MMM, dd yyyy"));`

Comment: I have Checked them all..Still cant figure out what is the Error,Where i am going Wrong? Is it while Adding Params in the Report Design?

Comment: Did you try formatting the date? Also, have you added a default value to the parameter? `FromDate.DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM, dd yyyy")`